# how to show background image with a button on it

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, internet-explorer

I am facing an issue with background-size property in IE. So, to compensate this, i tried using  below code

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='XYZ.jpg',sizingMethod='scale');
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='XYZ.jpg',sizingMethod='scale')";
```

This is working fine, but the problem is, it taking few seconds to load the background image.

My requirement is to show one button with a background image(My image will have some text and other stuff). I also tried to paint an image with input tag and a button on screen, but not able to figure out on how to bring the button on the image(presently they are coming one after the other).
Please suggest me a solution.

I am using `IE 8`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what the real problem is (try to add more code?) but if the problem is that button is displayed before the image is loaded, then you can cache the image and when it's loaded then display both image and button.

```
new img = document.createElement('img');
img.onload = function() { /* ... display image and button */ }
img.src = 'http://path/to/your/image';
```

Or if the problem is positioning, use this:

```
<div style="position:relative; width:10em; height:1em">
    <img src="..." style="position:absolute; left:0; top:0; width:100%; height:100%; display:block;">
    <button onclick="..." style="position:absolute; left:0; top:0; width:100%; height:100%; display:block;">
</div>
```

Edit: As mentioned in comment:

```
<div style="position:relative; width:1024px; height:768px; background:url('...');">
    <button onclick="..." style="position:absolute; left:480px; top:376px; width:64px; height:16px;">
</div>
```

Comment: HI, Thanks for the solution. But i guess my requirement is not clear to u. I wanted to show a full size image in the background (like 1024X736) and paint a button on that image(at the center of the image)

Comment: I've added code to display button over and background image, but I'm not sure it's what you want. Maybe if you include some JSfiddle example...

Comment: Hi, Your solution is working. ThanQ :) Can u help me on how to fit the background image to the browser window. Presently some part of the image is not getting displayed(i'm not using the css properties that u suggested, i'm using them as 100%). My image resolution is 1920X975

Comment: Look at source code of http://eclipse.chobits.ch/ , it shows how to center something in the middle of the browser window. I hope it will help you.

Comment: Hi Radek, i wanted to show the full image on the background, but this is not happening. if i'm trying to control it with width:1024px; height:768px; it is painting the screen up to that width and remaining part is getting trimmed. Can u pls help me with this.